# Use Zip to Pre-Populate City/State Form with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm running into a problem that I can solve fine by just submitting a form and calling a db to retrieve/echo the information, but AJAX seems to be a bit different for doing this (and is what I need).  Earlier in a form process I ask for the zip code like so:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" size="5" id="zip" />
```

Then I have a button to continue, but this button just runs a javascript function that shows the rest of the form.  When the rest of the form shows, I want to pre-populate the City input with their city, and pre-populate the State dropdown with their state.  I figured I would have to find a way to set city/state to variables, and echo the variables into the form.  But I can't figure out how to get/set those variables with AJAX as opposed to a form submit.  Here's how I did it without ajax:

```
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip']);
$q = " SELECT city FROM citystatezip WHERE zip = $zip"; 
$r = mysql_query($q); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r); 
$city = $row['city'];
```

Can anybody help me out with using AJAX to set these variables?  Thanks!

Comment: Your SQL should work regardless of the method with which you're calling.  Do you have an AJAX listener script setup?  What happens when you hit it manually?  What happens when you call this AJAX script from your javascript?  Can you not set the values of the form variables from javascript?

Comment: The SQL does work fine if I submit the form to call it.  I don't have any AJAX setup, I've never worked with it like this before.  And I can't set the values using JS because I have to call the server to get the city and state.

Comment: Include the jQuery library and use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: You need something on the server to answer the request.